# Shell script passing asterisks

Tags: shell

I have inherited a shell script that executes a command with variables. 
I have added further details, sorry I was not clear on the details earlier, I am not very familiar to Shell scripting

```
#!/bin/sh
ExecuteCommand () {
    Command=`echo -e ${2}`
    Comment=${4}
    echo "INFO: ${Comment}"
    echo "# ${Comment}" >> ${CommandsLog}
    echo "${Command}" | paste -s -d' ' | tee -a ${CommandsLog}
    echo "" | tee -a ${CommandsLog}
    eval ${Command} | grep -v "ERROR : bad number of fields"
    ExitCode=$?
    if [ "${ExitCode}" != "0" ] && [ "${ExitCode}" != "" ]
    then
        exit ${ExitCode}
    fi
}

set Option = echo ` '.*(def).*'`
echo $Option
ExecuteCommand -command "abc ${Option}"
```

Looking at the logs the command being executed is without the '`*`';
i.e.

```
.*(def).*
abc '. (def). '
```

Since the command is missing the '*', the command fails
I have tried to pass the variable in '$Option' but that to fails.
How do I pass the '*' to the command.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The shebang line is OK. The next line appears to execute a command called `ExecuteCommand` with one option that is `-command` and another which is the result of expanding `"abc ${Option}"`, but there's nothing in the script that sets `${Option}`, so it is either empty or an environment variable — but you've told us nothing about what is in the environment variable. The third line of code chooses to run whatever is in `${Option}` as the name of a command — or, if there is nothing in `${Option}`, it runs the command `is` instead — with some arguments. What's going on?

Comment: Now, if the 'third line of script' is really running text that says "the environment variable `Option` is set to `'.*(def).*'`, then we're in a different ball-game (probably cricket rather than baseball).  However, there are still many unknowns about how the information is passed to the log file.  That said, it isn't obvious how you get blanks for stars.  In general, quoting the stars prevents them being expanded.

Comment: With all the uncertainty correctly mentioned above, about the only suggestion would be to include single-quotes around `${Option}` in your command. (e.g. `"abc '${Option}'"`. I cannot guarantee that will fix the issue, but it is within the range of possibilities.

Comment: I don't know what the line ``set Option = echo ` '.*(def).*'` `` is supposed to do.  What it does for me, given that I don't have a command `.*(def).*` kicking around, is sets `$1` to `Option`, `$2` to `=` and `$3` to `echo`.  It also generated the error message `bash: .*(def).*: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the original author wasn't very familiar with shell scripting either.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here exactly, but here's my interpretation of what I believe is supposed to be going on here (?):

```
#!/bin/sh 

LOGFILE=~/mylog
PS4="Command: ->  " ## You can set this you don't like the default "+".

dowithlog(){
  (set -x; $1) 2>>"$LOGFILE"
  echo "Comment: $2" >> "$LOGFILE"
}

dowithlog "ls /tmp" "Ok, cool beans."
```